# Prove $(A×C)\cap(B×D)=(A\cap B)×(C\cap D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $(A×C)\cap(B×D)=(A\cap B)×(C\cap D)$

I would like to know how to prove above using the definition of the cartesian product or properties and theorems regarding the cartesian product.

I came this far. But got stuck.

$\implies (A\cap B)×(C\cap D)\\ 
\implies [(A\cap B)×C]\cap [(A\cap B)×D]\\ 
\implies (A×C)\cap(B×C)\cap (A×D)\cap(B×D)\\
$

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Showing your attempts will avoid people downvoting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
&(x, y)\in (A\times C)\cap (B\times D) &\iff\\
&(x, y)\in (A\times C) \wedge (x, y)\in (B\times D) &\iff\\
&x\in A \wedge y\in C \wedge x\in B \wedge y\in D &\iff\\
&x\in (A\cap B) \wedge y\in (C\cap D) &\iff\\
&(x, y)\in (A\cap B)\times (C\cap D) &
\end{aligned}$$

therefore $(A\times C)\cap (B\times D) = (A\cap B)\times (C\cap D)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y) \in (A×C)\cap(B×D)=(A\cap B)×(C\cap D)$ means

- $x\in A\ \&\ y\in C$ and also
- $x\in B\ \&\ y\in D.$

$(x,y)\in (A\cap B)×(C\cap D)$ means

- $\big(x\in A$ and $x\in B\big)$ and also
- $\big(y\in C$ and $y\in D\big).$

Answer (score 0):

I'd prove it by showing they are subsets of each other.  And I'd do that by taking an $(m,n) \in (A\times B)\cap (B\times D)$ and showing it is in $(A\cap B)\times (C\cap D)$:

Suppose $(m,n) \in (A\times B) \cap (B\times D)$ then $(m,n) \in (A\times B)$ so $m\in A$ and $n \in B$.  But also $(m,n) \in B\times D$ so $m \in B$ and $n \in D$.  so $m \in A$ and $m \in B$ so $m \in A\cap B$.  And $n \in B$ and $n \in D$ so $n \in B\cap D$.  But I have no way of knowing whether $n \in C$ or not.  So I have no way of knowing if $n \in C\cap D$.  But I do know $n \in B$ and $n \in D$ so $n \in B\cap D$.  So $m \in A\cap B$ and $n \in B\cap D$ so $(m,n) \n (A\cap B)\times (B\cap D)$.

So $(A\times B)\cap (B\times D) \subset (A\cap B)\times (B \cap D)$ but we have no way of knowing if $(A\times B)\cap (B\times D) \subset (A\cap B)\times (B \cap D)$ or not.

So We can't prove your claim.

And I'd do the same for an $(w,u) \in (A\cap B) \times (C\cap D)$ to show $w\in A \cap B$ so $w \in A$ and $w\in B$.  And $u \in (C\cap D)$ so $u \in C$ and $u \in D$. But we have no way of telling if $u\in B$ or not.

So $w \in A$ and $u\in C$ so $(w,u)\in A\times C$.   And $w \in B$ and $u \in D$ so $(w,u)\int B\times D$.  So $(w,u)$ is in both $A\times C$ and in $B\times D$ so $(w,u) \in (A\times C)\cap (B\times D)$.  But we don't know if $(w,u) \in (A\times B) \cap(b\times D)$.

So $(A\cap B) \times (C\cap D)\subset (A\cap C) \times (B\cap D)$ but we can't prove $(A\cap B) \times (C\cap D)\subset (A\times B) \cap (B\times D)$.